# Bootstrap how to align items from vertical to horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement something responsive like the page [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com). It has a logo, DuckDuckGo literal, and a search box. When I shrink the browser to a almost horizotal bar, the three components align from vertical to horizontal, and the logo and literal also become smaller. I wonder how to implement it through bootstrap?

Comment: This is basic html and css skills. Please try something and then ask a question. The circles are displayed inline-block or inline with a text center the rest is an search input (in bootstrap read the docs on forms). The hamburger with the side navigation is not something that comes with Bootstrap.

Comment: Do you see the responsive feature when the page has low height and long width?

Comment: The layout is not done correctly for that. I see crappy implementation of responsive layouts all the time, lots of themes suck that way too. Oh well. If you clear your content and use static or relative positions, remove the floats or start off with no floats, this will be avoided.

Comment: http://bombdiggitydesign.com/jsbin/duck.png -- bad job

Comment: Oh i meant this: http://postimg.org/image/r2sl8xmgj/. They changed the layout from vertical to horizontal.

Comment: You can open up their style sheet and take a look. Probably hiding and showing at that breakpoint but could be done with jQuery or flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you read the bootstrap documentation in this link below:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

In this link you have all the information about mobile resolution, media screen and etc.

I did a sample to help you of start doing your website:

The HTML code:

```
<div class="general">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="col-xs-12">
            <img class="logo" src="http://blog.kajrietberg.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/HTML5_oval_logo.png">
                <span class="col-xs-12 title">alexfqc sample</span>
        </header>

            <main>
                <input class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-lg-offset3 col-lg-6">                
            </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
body{
    background-color:#F7F7F7;    
    min-width:320px;
}

general{
    width:100%;
}

header{
    margin-top:40px;
}

.logo{
    width:35%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
}

.title{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
}

input{
    height:30px;   
}
```

The bootstrap has a class "container" that auto scale to the screen resolution, the class col-xs-12 means that this has `width:100%` to screens until 768px.
Bootstrap has a division in 12 blocks, then you have to insert class width the resolutions based in this 12 blocks. To have a `width:50%` in resolutions until 768px you just have to insert the class col-xs-6.
If you do not insert the classes to the other resolutions (col-sm- , col-md- , col-lg- ) the `width:100%` from col-xs-12 will be replicated to the other resolutions.

I change the margin and the width of input according width resolution:

col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 = 1 block to margin-left and 10 blocks to input width, 1 + 10 = 11 (1 block is missing to complete 12, this is to align horizontally this block in the center).

col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 = 2 blocks to marign-left and 8 blocks to width.

col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 = 3 blocks to margin-left and 6 blocks to width.

Comment: You sample scales well for different width, and I know how to do it, but it is not what I want. When the screen becomes a "horizontal bar" duckduckgo align the logo and search box to a single line and also change the size of the logo.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is use media queries. This link of mozilla can help you:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

A simple example in css would be like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
   .div1{
        width:50%;
        float:left;
   }
   .div2{
        width:50%;
        float:left;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) { 
   .div1{
        width:100%;
        float:left;
   }
   .div2{
        width:100%;
        float:left;
   }
}
```

if the screen is in landscape and max-width is 767 then the divs will positioneted side by side. Case the acreen is in landscape and min-width is 768 then the divs will have `width:100%`.